# Haskell functions response list more values than input parameter list size

Tags: haskell

The main idea is that I've two input lists that consists of tuples, list A(x,y) and list B(y,z) in output I need to compile list C that consists of elements (x,z) if y from A == y from B

In function cc there is recursive loop through all input tuples in list. Function getValue finds all tuples that correspond to (x,y) from A. The problem is that in getValue there's possibility to find more than one tuple. The question is how to add all those tuples from getValue to cc result list. Currently I have an error

```
Couldn't match type ‘(String, String)’ with ‘[(String, String)]’
```

For example for [(a, b), (e, b)] [(b,c), (b,d)] should give result [(a,c), (a,d), (e, c), (e,d)]

```
isInDictionary :: String -> [(String,String)] -> Bool
isInDictionary x [] = False
isInDictionary x((x1,y1):ys) = any (==x) (map fst ys) ||  x == x1

getValue :: (String,String) -> [(String,String)] -> [(String,String)]
getValue  (x,y)[] = []
getValue (x,y)((x1,y1):ys) = 
    if (y == x1) 
    then (x,y1) : getValue (x,y) ys
    else getValue (x,y) ys


cc :: [(String,String)] -> [(String,String)] -> [(String,String)]

cc [] ((x2,y2):ys) = []
cc ((x1,y1):xs) [] = []
cc [] [] = []
cc ((x1,y1):xs)((x2,y2):ys) = 
    if( isInDictionary y1 ys ) 
        then (getValue (x1,y1) ys) : cc xs ysa --fix head
    else if (y1 == x2)
        then ( (x1,y2) : cc xs ysa)
    else (cc xs ysa)
    where ysa = (ys ++ [(x2,y2)])
```

Comment: You probably should rewrite the title into something that reflects the question better. (For instance, you are not actually defining any higher order function here.)

Comment: You can do this with a one-line list comprehension: `[(fst x, snd y) | x <- a, y <- b, snd x == fst y]`, with `let a = [("a", "b"), ("e", "b")]` and `let b = [("b", "c"), ("b", "d")]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks unnecessarily complicated. Can't you just do this?

```
cc :: [(String,String)] -> [(String,String)] -> [(String,String)]
cc as bs = [(x, z) | (x, y1) <- as, (y2, z) <- bs, y1 == y2]
```

As for the type error in `(getValue (x1,y1) ys) : cc xs ysa`, that could be fixed by using `++` (concatenate lists) instead of `:`.